# Flattenings With 2 Invariable Lines

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

We have the matrix

$ $ $ $ $ $ **A** $= \begin{bmatrix}{6}&{2} \\ {9}&{3}
 \end{bmatrix}$

representing a flattening of the plane onto the line

$ $ $ $ $ $ $y=\frac{3}{2}x$

thus the line $y$ must be the *only* invariant line of $ $ **A** (since every point of the plane is ''flattened'' onto $y$).

Yet, **A** has 2 *distinct* eigenvalues, $0$ and $9$, which implies that **A** must have 2 invariant lines.

But as we just saw, this is not possible.

What's going on?

Comment: I want to try it but what did you mean by flattening of the plane onto the line $y=3x/2  $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$ is $(1,-3)$, so this eigenspace corresponds to the line $y=-3x$. Since the eigenvalue is $0$, $A$ maps this line to the point 
$(0,0)$. $\{(0,0)\}$ is indeed a subset of $y=-3x$, so it is invariant under $A$. The key is that just because the line $y=-3x$ is invariant under $A$ doesn't mean its image is the whole line; it only has to be a subset.

Comment: It seems my understand of invariant line is wrong.  Invariant lines aren't always mapped onto themselves then? A subset of the line is sufficient?

Comment: Exactly. In general, an invariant space of a linear transformation $T$ is a space $U$ with $T(U)\subseteq U$. It doesn't say anything about whether $T$ is injective on $U$. As you've seen, we need to define it this way so that every eigenvector-eigenvalue pair gives rise to an invariant line. If we required $T(U)=U$, then an eigenspace with eigenvalue $0$ wouldn't be invariant.